# Why Java Collections API does not have Tree implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Just out of curiosity, I recently had to use a tree for one of my programs, i had to build a binary tree myself, but why does the Collections API does not have a default implementation of tree(or even a binary tree)?

I think there should be some strong reason why they decided not to include it in collections API.

Comment: TreeSet and TreeMap are two collections backed up by a binary tree.

Comment: Im not talking only of Binary tree, Why dont we have a generalized tree implementation, a Tree Inteface ?

Comment: there are lot of external libraries, which give this kind of functionality, rather it could have been included in Collections API itself, my questions is why it is not included as a general data-structure in collection API of java.?

Comment: You'd need to ask James Gosling. No one here can answer your question with any authority. Anything anyone would have to say would be merely speculation and opinion.

Comment: javax.swing.tree.TreeModel is a tree. I've never used it outside of Swing, but I don't see why it couldn't be.

Comment: you do have treeset and tree map.

Comment: @BrianRoach  Not James gosling. We need to ask Joshua Bloch:)

Comment: Make sure you close this one because its actually interesting.  Power trip.

Comment: `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` are always confusing names for tree based implementation of `Map` and `Set`

Comment: Great question. TreeMap and TreeSet can't contain elements with identical key, we definitely need a regular sorted Tree implementation.

Answer (score 22):

> I think there should be some strong reason why they decided not to include it in collections API.

I think that the reason is that nobody has come up with a good API for trees that is both

- general purpose enough to cover a wide range of use-cases, and
- useful enough to compensate for the performance and usability overheads of being general.

(And where do you stop? Tree? Binary tree? N-ary tree? DAG? Graph?)

It is worth noting that neither Apache Commons Collections or Google Collections (aka Guava) have a tree API.  However, there is an active Guava issue on this topic - http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=174 - so clearly at least *some* people agree with your point of view.

**UPDATE**

As of version 15.0, Guava now has tree support in the form of the `TreeTraverser` and `BinaryTreeTraverser` classes.  But this may not be what you expect.  In truth, these classes don't actually implement the tree data structure.  Instead, you have to do this in a generic type parameter.  Further to that, the `Traverser` classes even avoid making assumptions about the APIs of the node type.  They do this by being abstract classes, and requiring the concrete traverser subtype to implement the operations that interrogate the tree; e.g. to get a node's children.

---

FWIW, `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` are not "tree APIs".  They are tree-based implementations of the `Map` and `Set` APIs.  The tree-ness is totally concealed by the public APIs, making these two classes completely unsuitable for use as general purpose trees.

Answer (score 13):

IMHO, theoretically, Tree is not a type of collection, it's just a type of implementation. I mean there are abstract collections such as Set (unordered set of entries), List (ordered set of entries), Map (two sets of entries with relations between them), and there are their implementations: array, list (e.g. ArrayList and LinkedList), HashSet etc., all of them have their own advantages and disadvantages. Thus, Tree is just one of implementations (for lists, e.g.) which may give you (roughly) faster search than array but no access by index.

BTW, there is TreeMap ("Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation") and TreeSet ("A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap.") classes in Java.

Comment: This. Collections are not defined by their data structures, but their promises on performance with regard to insertion, deletion and lookup.  The details of implementation are supposed to be irrelevant, you choose the container based on what your usage requirements are. For example, if you needed a container where the elements are always sorted and the lookup should be O(log n), then you need a Set or SortedMap. It shouldn't matter how the implementation fulfils the performance guarantees.

Comment: I disagree.  Collections are defined by their contracts.  `Set`s make no guarantee of order (and hence have no indexed access), but guarantee no duplicates. `List`s guarantee order, but allow duplicates. `Map`s include relationships between the elements.  The fact that you can use Trees to implement some (all?) of these is irrelevant.  You could, for example, use a `List` to implement a `Set` (e.g. `LinkedHashSet`).  There is more than one way to implement a Tree, too.

Answer (score -2):

java.util.TreeMap is an implementation of Red and Black Tree.

Comment: I know TreeMap exists, but its a more specific form of a tree data-structure, why dont we have a more general tree implementation, as we have for List and Set. why the creators of Collections API decided not to give a generalized form of a tree.? May be they could have given an inteface Tree<K,V> and its implementations as BinaryTree, AVLTree, RedBlackTree?

Comment: I agree with Artem Zh.'s answer. Tree is just a specific form of data structure to hold a "collection" of entities.

Comment: TreeMap - not good enough, can't hold multiple elements with the same key (and different value)